# how to reflect <select> disable state on "Heapbox" plugin

Tags: jquery, css, heapbox

Is there any way to apply a class on heapbox html if select tag is disabled?

```
<select name="select-name" id="select-id" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Heapbox have no such feature this is what i did:

```
$("select").each(function () {
    if($(this).is(':disabled')){
        $(this).wrapAll(" <div class='select--disabled'></div>");
    }
}); 
$('select').heapbox();
```

Then using css:

```
.select--disabled .heapBox{
    cursor: default;   
    pointer-events: none;
}
.select--disabled .holder{
    /* Style for the disabled state */
    background-color: #404040;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #5A5A5A;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot overwrite disabled by css class.
Use javascript to change disable to enable. 
$('#select-id').prop('disabled', false);

Comment: i dont want to change disabled state to enable... i want my disabled select element to stay disabled even after applying heapbox plugin...

Comment: Use $('#select-id').prop('disabled', 'disabled');